# Xcode Debug Scheme

Tags: swift, xcode

I have debug scheme set up and the DEBUG flag set to 1 on my preprocessor macros, but when I set up something like this:

```
func print(_ object: Any) {
#if DEBUG
    Swift.print(object)
#endif
```

}

it is not printing even in debug mode.  How would I go about correcting this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Build Settings** and add `-D DEBUG` to **Other Swift Flags**.

[image: Other Swift flags]

Then this will work properly:

```
#if DEBUG
    print("This is DEBUG")
#else
    print("This is not DEBUG")
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had that as well but it looks like someone else on the repo removed the debug flags from the debug settings.  I didn't even think about double checking it because it had been so long ago

Comment: This code is now crashing my app whenever I get to a print function in a release build.  do you have any idea why?